# Image Intervention URL Manipulation shows blank image

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I'm trying to use the url manipulation of the Image Intervention package to handle image via url this [tutorial](http://image.intervention.io/use/url). But the browser returns an empty image like this:

[image: error]

I changed these line in the config file:

```
'route' => 'imagecache',
'paths' => array(
        storage_path('app/images'),
    ),
```

The url that I tried is like this: localhost:3500/imagecache/original/{file_name}

And leave everything else the same
So are there any steps that I'm missing?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/493).
There are some blank spaces before the `<?php` tag in the `config/imagecache.php` file. Delete them and everything starts working fine